# The 'source' button in basic ckeditor is not displaying

Tags: ckeditor

I have downloaded and installed the Basic package of Version 4.5.9 but the Source button does not display. This is my config file:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here.
    // For complete reference see:
    // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

    // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for a single toolbar row.
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'Source', 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
        { name: 'forms' },
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
        { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
        { name: 'tools' },
        { name: 'others' }
    ];

    // The default plugins included in the basic setup define some buttons that
    // are not needed in a basic editor. They are removed here.
    config.removeButtons = 'Cut,Copy,Paste,Undo,Redo,Underline,Strike,Subscript,Superscript';

    // Dialog windows are also simplified.
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'link:advanced';
};
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you're not supposed to capitalize `source`

Comment: Thanks Matti. Sadly it does not make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Source code editing](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/sourcearea.html) is not available in the Basic package as you can see in the [Compare presets](http://ckeditor.com/presets) table. You need to add the [Source Editing Area](http://ckeditor.com/addon/sourcearea) plugin (or [Source Dialog](http://ckeditor.com/addon/sourcedialog) if it's for inline editing) to your build first. [Use CKBuilder](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_plugins) for this.

Comment: Glad to hear this. If it solves your problem, accept the answer to make it more useful for other users looking for a solution to the same issue in the future.

Comment: Thank you Anna. My first time with Stack; didn't realise how it all worked!

Answer (score 0):

The better way to solve this is creating an new CKeditor https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30450260)